# Trying to use Interface for assigning

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I am declaring a interface as a type but I can not set the properties because it errors out since it's null

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export interface IClipboard extends mongoose.Document {
    current: string;
}

export const ClipboardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    current: { type: String, required: true }
});

const Clipboard = mongoose.model<IClipboard>("Clipboard", ClipboardSchema);
export default Clipboard;


import { IClipboard, default as Clipboard } from "../models/Clipboard";

export const paste = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    Clipboard.findById(process.env.PASTE, (error: Error, clipboard: IClipboard) => {
        clipboard.current = req.query.current; // clipboard is null
        clipboard.save();
        res.json(clipboard);
    });
};
```

How can I user the interface to set the properties?

Comment: It seems like `IClipboard` cannot be imported. Is there an error during the compilation?

Comment: There is no error, I have edited the code to display the full code

Comment: Now it seems that there is an issue about the `findById` method behavior and not about the TypeScript interface.